# Graphics deprecation in blackberry game development

Tags: blackberry, graphics

I had a problem on this matter, I'm using Eclipse with JDK 6.0
How can I resolve this problem:

Here's my code

```
public void processLevel(){

        OBJ tempObjects;

        if(mygfx.getBackPos() % 25 == 0){

            tempObjects = new EnemyDrone(rndGenerator.nextInt() % Graphics.getScreenWidth(), 0 );

            tempObjects.setY(tempObjects.getY() - tempObjects.getmybitmap().getHeight() + 3);

            gameObjects.addElement(tempObjects);
        }
    }
```

the error says that "The method getScreenWidth() from the type Graphics is deprecated"

Thanks in advance guys.!!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should still be able to compile it with that code; deprecation is just a warning that the current way of doing something isn't the recommended way of doing it, and that there is a newer method that might have additional functionality or is better supported. In this case, you want to use `Display.getWidth()` to get the current width of the screen.

In general the documentation will say what method a deprecated method has been replaced with. For example, if you check out [the documentation for the Graphics class in BB 6.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#getScreenWidth%28%29), it will say to use [the static getWidth method of the Display class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html#getWidth%28%29) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should now use `getWidth()` of `Display` in [net.rim.device.api.system.Display](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html). The  [Deprecated API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/deprecated-list.html) page is also useful.